# Spring form binding to Set inside c:forEach

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc, jstl

I am using the Spring `form` tag library for form binding in my JSP. My command object contains a `Set` and I would like to iterate over that set using JSTL `<c:forEach>` and create a Spring `<form:input>` for each object in my set. I have seen how to do this with `List`:

```html
<form:form>
  <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="item" varStatus="status" >
    <form:input path="itemList[${status.index}].name" />
  </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

My problem is that I am using an unordered `Set` and I don't believe that I can use the `index` property. What is the best practice for adding the contents of a `Set` to a Spring-bound form? I think I just need to convert to a `List`, but I am interested in any possible alternatives.

Comment: In my case, I have to get from a jsp page the checked properties for each user from a list, so I have to use the list in my form-backing object, can some one help me in that, this is the link of my problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/11478816/1458508

Comment: The above JSP code is not working in Websphere, getting below error. `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'xxxx[0]' of bean class [com.xxx.yyy.conf.xxxx]: Bean property 'xxxx[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

Comment: anybody has an issue with this in Websphere 7 application server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form-backing object should contain this data in a `List`, really. It doesn't make much sense to iterate over the set as the iteration order is not guaranteed to mean anything - and of course there is no concept of an `index` for a Set. I would imagine you probably have a certain desired order for these elements to appear on the page.

Comment: That really does make sense. Thanks for your answer.