# JSP form:checkbox into a c:foreach

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, taglib

Similar problems are invoked in many posts in this forum; but no one has a solution that specific one, I thank you for helping me in this :

I'm using spring to develop a web application,
I don't know what I should put in the path of the form:checkbox tag which inside the c:foreach one, here is my code :

```
<c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person" varStatus="i">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${person.firstName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.lastName}" /></td> 
        <td><form:checkbox path="person.rights" value="Download"/>Download </td>
        <td><form:checkbox path="person.rights" value="Delete"/>Delete </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

'`rights`' is a list of Strings as it defined in the spring documentation, it has a getter and a setter like the other properties, my checkboxes work outside the `c:foreach` tag, but when including them into this tag this exception is generated :

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'person' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'person' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

do you have an idea about what the problem is ??

Comment: Please post how person class rights property get/set defined.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is not in my getters and setter, it's in the 'path'; 
'String [] rights= new String[]{};


 public String[] getRights() {
  return rights;
 }
 
 public void setRights(String[] rights) {
  this.rights = rights;
 }'

Comment: Shouldn't those two checkboxes be different attributes? Why both pointing to same attribute of person?

Comment: The problem is because 'person' is declared by the foreach tag; so it's not recognized by the controller bean as a modelattribute,
even if i use things like path="persons${i.index}.rights" it doesn't work, I did a lot of search about this in fact but still don't have a solution

Comment: @thinksteep >> because it's a list of rights, if the checkbox is checked, the 'value' of the tag will be added to the list, so if we check the both cases, we'll get a list rights which have 2 elements {"Download","Delete"}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937743/how-to-inject-an-int-array-in-spring-bean

Answer (score 4):

This problem is strangely undocumented on most places. Here is an extract from the links I am posting below. The gist is that we need a static placeholder which maps to the type instead of the value of the bean. So anything inside a ${} will not work out. For this, and in the specific case of using a JSTL loop operator `<c:forEach>` with s[ring form tld, we should refer to the type information in each iteration using the `varStatus` attribute of the `<c:forEach>` operator, just like indices of an array, and thus refer to the inner properties of the iterable collection using `.` on the collection variable accessible via the outermost bean backing up the form.

For example:

```
<c:forEach items="${teamslist_session.teams}" var="team" varStatus="teamsLoop">
<form:input path="teams[${teamsLoop.index}].name"/>
</c:forEach>
```

where:

- `teamList_session` is the bean backing up the form
- `teams` is the collection of beans the properties of which we need to set in the `path` attribute
- `var` is the a reference to each member of the `teams` collection
- `teamsLoop` is the iteration index, which is used in the line below to refer to the say, `i`th element's bean's property called `name`

Please refer to the following links for more information:
[Forum Discussion - See the last post](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-85869.html)
[The link provided for reference in link 1](http://blog.vergiss-blackjack.de/2010/04/iterating-over-nested-objects-in-a-spring-form/)